# How to visualize a pdf in Java Swing frame using Apache pdfbox 2.0.8 whitout converting it to an image

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm looking for sample codes that allow me to display a PDF file in a Java Swing window. I saw an example in Apache SVN but it turns them into images, besides it does not work because I have particular fonts that it can not handle.

https://svn.apache.org/viewvc/pdfbox/branches/2.0/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/rendering/CustomPageDrawer.java?revision=1771345&view=markup

Thank you

Comment: So you want to render PDF? That's how it happens. You create a visual representation (i.e. an image) of the document and show it to the user. Same goes with HTML and everything else.

Comment: One of the `PDFRenderer.render*` methods allows to render into a graphics device. However the font problem that you mention won't go away. Most font problems go away by installing the fonts on your system. The least are the standard 14 fonts, i.e. the 4 times fonts (normal, bold, oblique, bold oblique), 4 courier, 4 helvetica / arial, symbol and zapf dingbats.